# how to send assertions to log file?

Tags: c#

I have assertions in my code that is creating popups in my ninjatrader. how can i prevent the popups and send the same message to a log file?

```
case MarketPosition.Long:
                {
                    Trace.Assert(exitStopOrderLong!= null,"exitStopOrderLong is null");
                    Trace.Assert(exitStopOrderLong.OrderState==OrderState.Accepted,string.Format("exitStopOrderLong is in invalid state{0}",exitStopOrderLong.OrderState));
                    double stopPrice=Instrument.MasterInstrument.Round2TickSize(Low[1]) -Instrument.MasterInstrument.TickSize/2 ;
                    ChangeOrder(exitStopOrderLong, exitStopOrderLong.Quantity, 0, stopPrice);


                    break;
                }
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vADbRMz.png]

Answer (score 0):

the answer is much more simpler. add to the app.config and put the target logfilename.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty5e4c4h.aspx